# Trigger to select data from another table and then update it to the current table SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, triggers

Please help me, I have a simple case that makes me little crazy, I have a table called `PRODUCTS` here is the structure

```
create table PRODUCT (
  ID_PRODUCT CHAR(5) primary key not null,
  NAME_PRODUCT CHAR(30),
  PRICE_PRODUCT integer
)
```

then the second table is `TRANSACTION`, here is the table structure

```
create table TRANSACTION (
  ID_TRANSACTION CHAR(5) primary key not null,
  ID_PRODUCT CHAR(30) REFERENCES PRODUCTS(ID_PRODUCT),
  PRICE integer,
  QUANTITY integer
)
```

After that I want to create a trigger that works when users fill data into the `ID_PRODUCT` column in the `TRANSACTIONS` table, it is automatically trigger will fetch/select data from the column `PRICE` in the `PRODUCTS` table according to `ID_PRODUCT` that has been inserted, then update the column `PRICE` in table `TRANSACTIONS`

I'm a starter in SQL Server,... I hope you want to help me in this case, because I have no idea & don't know what I have to do, thanks

Comment: Since the PRODUCT (no "S") is defined as CHAR(5) in the PRODUCT table, your foreign-key should be: ID_PRODUCT CHAR(30) REFERENCES PRODUCTS(ID_PRODUCT) - also, PRICE columns are typically defined with type: MONEY. See my comment on Duncun's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this will probably do what you need:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER UpdateTransaction 
ON [TRANSACTION] 
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS 
BEGIN  

INSERT [TRANSACTION] (ID_TRANSACTION, ID_PRODUCT, PRICE, QUANTITY)
SELECT INSERTED.ID_TRANSACTION, INSERTED.ID_PRODUCT, PRODUCT.PRICE_PRODUCT, INSERTED.QUANTITY
FROM INSERTED
JOIN PRODUCT ON INSERTED.ID_PRODUCT = PRODUCT.ID_PRODUCT

END
```

It'll run `INSTEAD` of the normal insert and join the row to be `INSERTED` with the `PRODUCT` table, allowing it to insert the right `PRICE_PRODUCT`. You could do something similar for `UPDATE`'s if you need to.

On a side note, `TRANSACTION` is a terrible name for a table - it's a [reserved word in T-SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) (notice that it gets highlighted by your editor, and this website?) - it's part of the language, so I would avoid it in object names.

Perhaps naming your tables like this might be better:

```
TRANSACTION -> tbl_Transactions
PRODUCT -> tbl_Products
```

Comment: I upvoted since your answer is generally correct, but there are a couple of syntax errors. Here's a working SQLFiddle example based on your answer: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/16e60/1

Comment: Thanks - I've updated the code in the answer. Also, I didn't know about SQLFiddle - Cool!

Comment: I also learned from your answer - mutual edification - how grand!

Comment: Thanks for your help,... let me try it, if there is a error, i'll contact you soon

Answer (score 0):

You're having data duplication by having two columns in two tables that are connected (id *and* price). I suggest removing the `TRANSACTION.PRICE` column.
You could instead create a `VIEW`:

```
CREATE VIEW V_Transaction AS
  SELECT
    TRANSACTION.ID_TRANSACTION,
    TRANSACTION.ID_PRODUCT,
    TRANSACTION.QUANTITY * PRODUCT.PRICE_PRODUCT as PRICE,
    TRANSACTION.QUANTITY
  FROM
    TRANSACTION
    JOIN ID_PRODUCT ON TRANSACTION.ID_PRODUCT = PRODUCT.ID_PRODUCT
```

There is just no point (that I see) to store the price per produkt and the price per transaction

Comment: Opps, I misplaced my comment. Please disregard.

Comment: thanks for your help,... but the point is data on column PRICE table TRANSACTION should be inserted in database, not only view then just dissapear when we stop it.

Comment: If the price of the products change over time, you will need to store the price at time of sale on the transaction somewhere - that's what transaction type records are for. Yes, you could have a table of prices with from - to dates and link it all together, but just putting it on the transaction is simpler and faster.